# Wazuh Quickstart Erroring on wazuh-indexer install

Tags: wazuh

I am just finding wazuh and wanted to test it out. I have tried the step by step and the scripted. Cannot get it to work. So I am consolidating my deployment to just 1 VM and am trying to run the quickstart to get going. When I try to install I get the below error. I cannot find anything related to wazuh-indexer 4.3.1-1. Thoughts?

10/05/2022 12:52:37 INFO: Created wazuh-install-files.tar. It contains the Wazuh cluster key, certificates, and passwords necessary for installation.
10/05/2022 12:52:37 INFO: --- Wazuh indexer ---
10/05/2022 12:52:37 INFO: Starting Wazuh indexer installation.
Updating Subscription Management repositories.
EL-8 - Wazuh                                     75 kB/s | 3.4 kB     00:00
No match for argument: wazuh-indexer-4.3.1-1
Error: Unable to find a match: wazuh-indexer-4.3.1-1
10/05/2022 12:52:48 ERROR: Wazuh indexer installation failed.
10/05/2022 12:52:48 INFO: --- Removing existing Wazuh installation ---
10/05/2022 12:52:48 INFO: Installation cleaned. Check the /var/log/wazuh-install.log file to learn more about the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The root of that error is that the script is trying to download
`wazuh-indexer-4.3.1-1` instead of the current `wazuh-indexer-4.3.0-1`.
It seems that the production script included this bug for a short period of time. Please download the script and install it again.

Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. After waiting a few days, the bug was fixed. But am now hitting a new bug. When trying to run filebeat setup --dashboards. I get an error: Exiting: Kibana API is not available in Kibana version 1.2.0

I have the setting:

```
compatibility.override_main_response_version: true
```

on my `opensearch.yml` but still no avail.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the `wazuh-install` script, it is not required to perform any further configuration.

In order to troubleshoot this issue, could you please provide us with the following information:

- Architecture: Single host or multi-node
- Installation method: Step by step installation
- Documentation page you follow to install your environment
- OS of your nodes

I recommend you to join Wazuh slack channel (https://wazuh.com/community/) and move this issue there, or into the Wazuh google group in order to be able to correctly monitor this problem